# MYSQL Return all categories with related post count

Tags: mysql

I am trying to return all categories and a count of any related/tagged posts associated with them.

Here is an example of the table structure.

**Posts Table**

```
id      name    user_id
1       post 1  1
2       post 2  2
3       post 3  1
```

**Tags Table**

```
id      tag_name
1       Category 1
2       Category 2
3       Category 3
```

**Posts Tags Pivot**

```
id      tag_id  post_id
1       3       2
2       3       2
3       1       3
```

And here is a breakdown of the queries

**Get All Tags**

```
SELECT t.tag_name
FROM tags t
GROUP BY
    t.tag_name
```

This returns all of my tags

**Get All Tags With Post Count**

```
SELECT t.tag_name, count(p.id) as count FROM products p
LEFT JOIN tags_pivot c ON p.id = c.post_id
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.id = c.tag_id
WHERE p.user_id = 1
GROUP BY
    t.tag_name
```

This returns tags only where results/post where found. I'd like to return all tags even if the count is 0 and have the count show 0 for that particular tag. Is there a way to structure the query like this? I had tried with left outer join but I still kept getting the same results.

Comment: Start from tags table then do left join to tags_pivot and eventually posts

Comment: The p.parent_id and table products are missing in the above snippets. Can you update the final query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to get all the **tags** considered, your base table should be `tags` table and your `LEFT JOIN` should begin from there. [LEFT JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx) always considers all the data from the **Left most** table and joins only those data from the right table which matches the join condition. So all the `tags` are considered (since it is the left-most table), however only those `posts` are considered which are in the **pivot table**. Try the following:

```
SELECT t.tag_name, COUNT(p.id) as count 
FROM tags AS t 
LEFT JOIN tags_pivot AS c ON t.id = c.tag_id 
LEFT JOIN posts AS p ON p.id = c.post_id 
GROUP BY
    t.tag_name
```

**EDIT** Based on OP's comments, only those posts to be considered where `user_id = 1`. To achieve that, we add an extra `AND` requirement in `LEFT JOIN` on `posts` table. Here is the updated query:

```
SELECT t.tag_name, COUNT(p.id) as count 
FROM tags AS t 
LEFT JOIN tags_pivot AS c ON t.id = c.tag_id 
LEFT JOIN posts AS p ON p.id = c.post_id AND p.user_id = 1
GROUP BY
    t.tag_name
```

Comment: The query is successful, but if I add a where clause to this, it returns only a few of the categories and not all of them showing the count as 0.

Comment: @Miura-shi what are you adding in WHERE clause ? You can solve that using IF. Please explain, I can edit and give an addon query

Comment: I've added the extra field to the posts table as an example in my initial post. The clause would be WHERE p.user_id = 1 for example.

Comment: @Miura-shi I have added an edit. You basically add a new AND condition in your left join with posts table.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Can you link to or explain why this allows all tags to return and also return 0 for the count still?

Comment: @Miura-shi LEFT JOIN always considers all the data from Left most table and joins only those data from the right table which matches the join condition. So all the tags are considered (since it is the left-most table), however only those posts are considered which are in the pivot and have user_id = 1. Hope that makes sense ?

Comment: It does! Thank you for the extra clarification!

Answer (score 0):

use left table name 1st which table value you want to contain with count values , for your sample data either tags_pivot  or tags can be started left table

```
 SELECT t.tag_name, count(p.id) as count FROM tags_pivot c 
   LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.id = c.tag_id
    LEFT JOIN products p
      ON p.parent_id = c.post_id    
    GROUP BY
        t.tag_name
```